# dplyr: Read rows from file and apply replace function

Tags: r, function, replace, dplyr

A script runs following dplyr line to replace a string in a data frame:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(city=replace(city, city=="Lower East, NY", "Manhattan, NY"))
data <- data %>% mutate(city=replace(city, city=="East Palo Alto, CA", "Palo Alto, CA"))
.. (more than 100 replacements)
```

**Question:**

Would it be possible to put all relevant replacements into an external .txt file (or tab?) and run the function across all rows in that file? dplyr solutions appreciated.

Thanks for the great support here, the learning curve is great so far!

Comment: Create a key/value dataset and do a merge to replace the values in the current dataset. i.e. `keyvaldat <- data.frame(city = c("Lower East, NY", "East Palo Alto, CA"), repl = c("Manhattan, NY", "Palo Alto, CA"), stringsAsFactors= FALSE); left_join(data, keyvaldat) %>% mutate(city =ifelse(!is.na(city), repl, city))`

Comment: I would suggest exporting `unique(data$city)` as a `.csv` to create the LHS of your key/value table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an external .csv file with two columns, `city` and `new_city`, where `city` **exactly** matches city in your original data file, you can use `dplyr::left_join()` and `dplyr::coalesce()`

```
library(tidyverse)

# read in your new, two column csv
replacementcities  <- read.csv('replacement-cities.csv')

fixeddata  <- data %>%
    # join the two data frames where the city columns match
    left_join(replacementcities, by = 'city') %>%

    # replace city with whatever is not NA, using new_city first 
    mutate( city = coalesce(new_city, city) ) %>%

    # drop the, now unnecessary, new_city column
    select(-new_city)
```